# How to run javascript from a new window onto existing window

Tags: javascript

```js
const winHtml = `<button id="cool">Run code on other window</button>`;

const winUrl = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([winHtml], { type: "text/html" })
);

const win = window.open(
    winUrl,
    "win",
    `width=800,height=400,screenX=200,screenY=200`
);
```

So I want to be able to run code from a new Window, opened with JS. This is not a new Browser tab, it is a new Browser window with html inserted. Is it possible to run code from it to the existing browser window?

Comment: Try [`postMessage`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Comment: Could you give an example of how I would use it? Do I add an eventlistner to the button or...

Comment: There are examples on the [documentation page linked above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#example).

Comment: Also, if you go to any search engine and write down window open javascript, you will have your answer in no time

Comment: I tried to use postMessage as an example but it just alerts, "object MessageEvent", and I have parameters.

Comment: Same origin: `opener.document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML = "hello from the other side"`

Comment: @ScriptSecureServices You have a [MessageEvent](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent) object, so get its [properties](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/MessageEvent#properties) (the linked example also demonstrates this). Don’t use `alert`. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and use `console.log`. What do you mean by _“I have parameters”_?

Comment: ```window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  
  alert(event)
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.com")
    return;


}, false);